# Array.push is not sorted correctly when logging it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I receive an object from a REST endpoint which contains some values. I have processed the data correctly and access it, and use `array.push` to put it into an empty array.

However, the array is never sorted correctly. What gives?

Some sample code:

```
    let high = data.High;
    let medium = data.Medium;
    let low = data.Low;
    let exampleArr = [];

    exampleArr.push(
        {
            high,
            medium,
            low
        }
    );
    console.log(exampleArr)
```

The output in the console is consistently:

```
high: object
low: object
medium: object
```

The nested information in each is an object, but that shouldn't affect the sorting?

Comment: what kind of sorting are you talking about? there is no sorting for object keys

Comment: Objects are not ordered collections of key-value pairs. Arrays are ordered, so if you push another object into it, this object will be on the second place. But object properties itself are unordered by design.

Comment: I do get that; but I'm pushing them into an array.. Shouldn't the key value there be sorted? Or should I let each of the high, medium and low be converted to individual arrays first, and then push those three into an array containing them all?

Comment: _“but I'm pushing them into an array”_ - no, you are not pushing “them” (plural), you are pushing _one single object_. _“Or should I let each of the high, medium and low be converted to individual arrays first”_ - why convert them “to arrays”? You already have three single values - so push them, each, individually - without putting them into an array first (that’s what _you_ are doing with `{}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only adding one item ( the object with the three keys ) to your array, so at this point nothing can be sorted. If you will add more objects you can use array.sort with a compare function as a parameter to sort your objects based on objects keys.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are adding only one object to the array. In addition, `console.log` will order the fields of the single object alphabetically, rather than by insertion order. Hence you see high, low, medium.